# How to remove nan values from numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, nan, numpy-ndarray

I have some numpy.ndarray variables. They include nan values and I want to drop each nan value from them. Arrays contain int, float, str, etc. values. An example to these arrays:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' nan 'E' 'F']
```

another one:

```
[nan  1.]
```

And there might be a case where the array contains float, str and nan values. In this case how can I drop only nan values?

I used the following code:

```
x[:, ~np.isnan(x).any(axis=0)]
```

and get the following error:

```
ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Did you try pandas `isnull` ? This may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the `np.isnan()` is failing to deal with string types among your possible element types in collection. You could try to use `panda's` `isnull()` to remove `NaN` values.

```
import pandas as pa
import numpy as np

a = ['A', np.nan, np.nan, 1.67, 8]
a = [x for x in a if not pa.isnull(x)]
print(a)
```

Comment: Getting the error I mentioned above for the array with string values.

Answer (score 0):

There's function in **pandas** called `pandas.DataFrame.dropna` which drops all the columns with `nan` values. Just create DataFrame if you didn't, and do `df.dropna()`.

Comment: I don't want to drop columns with nan values. I just want to drop nan values and see what's left for each column.

Comment: If you are writing something as an answer, write the code and check it before. If it's just "Hope it will help", use the comments section.